# How to add custom Frame borders in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, border, frame

I'm building a GUI application with Tkinter. I am creating 9 buttons, 3 in each row. I want to make it so that the borders are drawn only between them, and there are no borders above and below. Can this be done with Tkinter?

```
    buttons_frame = [tk.Frame(
        self.root,
        highlightbackground="black",
        highlightcolor="black",
        highlightthickness=1,
        bd=0
    ) for i in range(9)]

    self.field_buttons = [tk.Button(
        buttons_frame[i],
        width=5,
        height=2,
        relief='flat',
        padx=1,
        font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'),
        command=lambda x=i: self.push(x)
    ) for i in range(9)]

    row, col = 1, 0
    for i in range(9):
        buttons_frame[i].grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='news')
        self.field_buttons[i].grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='news')
        col += 1
        if col == 3:
            row += 1
            col = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a single frame, but you can do it by placing a `ttk.Separator` between the rows and columns. Put the buttons in rows 0, 2, and 4, and in columns 0, 2, and 4. Then, put the separators in rows 1 and 3, and columns 1 and 3.

Start by creating a single frame for the buttons. Then, create the buttons as children of this frame. Then, use `grid` to distribute the buttons on every other row and in every other column.

Then, create four separators: two horizontal and two vertical. Put them in the rows and columns between the buttons and have them span all five rows and columns.

The following example illustrates the technique. I've added some exaggerated padding to make it a bit more obvious.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

button_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=0)
button_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

field_buttons = [tk.Button(
    button_frame,
    width=5,
    height=2,
    relief='flat',
    padx=1,
    font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'),
) for i in range(9)]

rows = [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
cols = [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]
for i in range(9):
    field_buttons[i].grid(row=rows[i], column=cols[i], sticky='news')

ttk.Separator(button_frame, orient="horizontal").grid(row=1, sticky="ew", columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Separator(button_frame, orient="horizontal").grid(row=3, sticky="ew", columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Separator(button_frame, orient="vertical").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns", rowspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Separator(button_frame, orient="vertical").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns", rowspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]